# Rewiring House (Coax and Ethernet)

Tags: wiring, drywall, data-wiring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I run ethernet, speaker wire, and coax through a wall into a crawlspace?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/how-do-i-run-ethernet-speaker-wire-and-coax-through-a-wall-into-a-crawlspace)

When my family moved into our house, there were holes in the floors where the coax cables meet the TV's. We've kept with this for a few years and have even pulled a few ethernet cables through the holes for our computers.

Next week we are having new flooring installed through the entire house. I don't want to be drilling any holes through our new floors. I would much rather have a wall plate with RJ45 & coax keystone jacks or something like this:

[image: coax and rj45 wall jack plate]

I would have no problem installing these jacks in the wall, except for the fact that I really don't want to have to tear the wall away.  We have a crawlspace where all of our wiring is ran to the holes in the floors. I believe I would have to tear the wall away, drill a hole through the sill plate between the wall studs for the cables to pass through from the crawl space. Does that all sound right? I've never replaced/repaired drywall before and I'm pretty sure it would look awful.

I couldn't find any articles or videos of someone rewiring their house with the purpose of not running data/a/v wires through the floor. I guess my question is how should I go about doing this?

Comment: Even if not closed as a dup, see my answer: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/how-do-i-run-ethernet-speaker-wire-and-coax-through-a-wall-into-a-crawlspace/3038#3038

Comment: I don't get it. You used a wire as a drill bit just behind the base board to make a reference hole? The wire actually drilled through the flooring? That's how it reads to me. The other comment about the installer's drill bit looks really promising to me.

Comment: Yes use the wire as a drill bit. Don't use the hole as a reference - use the wire itself. I added a picture and some more text to that answer.

Comment: Yes, the wire is a reference, it minimizes the amount of measuring you have to do since it can be difficult to find a wall through the subfloor from below. Since you're replacing your floors, and already have holes for the existing wiring, you can use your existing wiring or drill directly through the floor for your reference location. Regardless, you drill through the sill plate from below and only cut enough drywall to install a backless low voltage old work box, so there's no drywall repair.

Comment: I tend to agree that this is a duplicate. If you have a question that wasn't answered there, then edit your question to clarify and ping me in the comments so we can consider reopening it for you.